# PHP Postgresql using IN with pg_query_params

Tags: php, postgresql

Can I pass values into this query? If so, what is the format of `$arr`?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tree WHERE tree_id IN ($1);";
$result = pg_query_params($sql, [$arr]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tree WHERE tree_id = ANY ($1)";
$result2  = pg_query_params($sql2,[$arr]);
```

$arr format example = "{12,13}"

Comment: There must be as many parameters as values in the IN statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL statement contains an `IN` clause which takes a **varying number** of parameters, then it's somewhat tricky to use a parameterized query. As you've found out, you can solve this by using `ANY` instead of `IN` ([documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16)), and then passing a PostgreSQL array as the sole query parameter.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tab WHERE id = ANY ($1);';
$id_array = [ 1, 2, 3 ];        // id_array can be of any size
$result = pg_query_params($sql, [ toPostgresArray($id_array) ]);
```

Whereby `toPostgresArray()` is the following helper function, which converts a PHP array into a PostgreSQL array:

```
function toPostgresArray($values) {
    $strArray = [];
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if (is_int($value) || is_float($value)) {
            // For integers and floats, we can simply use strval().
            $str = strval($value);
        } else if (is_string($value)) {
            // For strings, we must first do some text escaping.
            $value = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $value);
            $value = str_replace('"', '\\"', $value);
            $str = '"' . $value . '"';
        } else if (is_bool($value)) {
            // Convert the boolean value into a PostgreSQL constant.
            $str = $value ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
        } else if (is_null($value)) {
            // Convert the null value into a PostgreSQL constant.
            $str = 'NULL';
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unsupported data type encountered.');
        }
        $strArray[] = $str;
    }
    return '{' . implode(',', $strArray) . '}';
}
```